# Msbuild windows store app (metro)

Tags: msbuild, windows-store-apps, hudson

I use nugget and Hudson to deploy our libraries to our enterprise for reuse.  We recently started work on windows store apps (formerly called Metro app). Hudson runs on a windows server 2008 box.  What do I need to install to compile from source to deploy to nuget.  Ms build doesn't find the target files needed.  Is there a specific SDK to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to solve this, I installed the 4.5 framework SDK.  After doing so, it was missing the target files, as I mentioned.  Then I simply copied target files from C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v11.0 on my local development machine to the same directory on the server.

MSBuild liked this and and it compiled without issues.